# PHP explode array then loop through values and output to variable

Tags: php, arrays

The string I am trying to split is `$item['category_names']` which for example contains `Hair, Fashion, News`

I currently have the following code:

```
$cats = explode(", ", $item['category_names']);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $categories = "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
```

I want the outcome of `$categories` to be like the following so I can echo it out later somewhere.

```
<category>Hair</category>\n
<category>Fashion</category>\n
<category>News</category>\n
```

Not sure if I am going the right way about this?

Comment: does it work? That's a pretty good smoke test. if you do `$categories .= ` it would at least do what you appear to be expecting.

Comment: $categories .= // concatenation missing

Comment: Did you try this code? Should work I think

Comment: I would explode on `,` and then trim the result, not explode on `, `

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in using the [simpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) object. It's a fairly simple and sturdy way of creating xml files

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your code you are overwritting the $categories variable in each iteration. The correct code would look like:

```
$categories = '';
$cats = explode(",", $item['category_names']);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $cat = trim($cat);
    $categories .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
```

update: as @Nanne suggested, explode only on ','

Comment: @AD7six nobody states that this is the only solution, it's actually fixed version of the OP's code; so yeah, it's the correct version of what OP's implementation.

Comment: except "what's wrong with my code" isn't the question that has been asked

Answer (score 2):

Without a for loop

```
$item['category_names'] = "Hair,   Fashion,   News";
$categories = "<category>".
        implode("</category>\n<category>", 
        array_map('trim', explode(",", $item['category_names']))) . 
        "</category>\n";
echo $categories;
```

Comment: This doesn't simplify anything and `array_map('trim', $cats)` is a lot simpler (and efficient) than using array_walk and create function

Comment: `array_map` is what I was looking for earlier! Thanks.

Comment: much better :) - formatting so it fits in the code window (or not using multiple php functions on one line) would make it easier to read

Answer (score 2):

**PHP explode  array  by loop**
demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/086402c33678fe20c4fbae6f2f5c18e77cb3fbc2

*its works for me*

```
<?php

$str = "name:john,hone:12345,ebsite:www.23.com";

$array=explode(",",$str);

if(count($array)!=0)
{
foreach($array as $value)
{

    $data=explode(":",$value);

      echo $data[0]."=".$data[1];


    echo ' ';

}
}
?>
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens  what do you want can u plz explain it

Comment: posting code with no explanation is perceived as low quality. You should also  explain why/how the code you posted does actually answer the question being asked. E.g.: "part  ... in the code so and so (as included in the question) contains an error. I.e. this and this is wrong. Instead it should be corrected like this ... This actually solves  your error because ....". PS: "read the source" is not high quality either.

Answer (score 1):

if you use this:

```
$cats = explode(", ", $item['category_names']);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
$categories = "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
```

the $categories string is overwritten each time, so "hair" and "fasion" are lost..

if you however add a dot before the equal sign in the for loop, like so:

```
$cats = explode(", ", $item['category_names']);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
$categories .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
```

the $catergories string will consist of all three values :)

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is this:

```
$categories = "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
```

You are overwriting `$categories` at each iteration, it should be:

```
$categories .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
```

**Not sure if I am going the right way about this?**

find and replace isn't what explode is for. If you just want to correct the code error - see above.

This is more efficient:

```
$categories = "<category>" .
    str_replace(', ', "</category>\n<category>", $input) . 
    "</category>\n";
```

And this also accounts for variable whitespace:

```
$categories = "<category>" . 
    preg_replace('@\s*,\s*@', "</category>\n<category>", $input) . 
    "</category>\n";
```