# how to write the php code to print the below example

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to the php so i don't know how to write the code . Friends help me to solve

I have created a table and populating from database and it has populated like this

consider this table below

```
TEAM     PLAYER
INDIA    DHONI,raina
AUS      WATSON,WARNE
NZ       VETTORI
```

but i want the table to be like this

```
TEAM    PLAYER 
INDIA   DHONI
        RAINA
AUS     WATSON
        WARNE
NZ      VETTORI
```

I have written the code like this

```
echo '<tr>
      <tbody>
         <td>'.$team.'</td> 
         <td>'.$cricket_names.'</td> // i have to code in this line and bring it down
         <td>'.____________________.'</td>
      </tr>';
```

Comment: How is your DB table set up? And how are you looping through the results? What does your query look like?

Comment: Is it just that you want to replace the commas with line breaks?

Comment: try to learn the basics and when you have a specific problem post it ...

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this chosen answer [PHP explode array then loop through values and output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650938/php-explode-array-then-loop-through-values-and-output-to-variable)

Within the loop you then say to  add a line-break (br within tags) [sorry, even if I try to write it as code it gets taken as a line-break here] after each name.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good database design.
Try something like this

```
//Teams Table
TEAM_ID TEAM
1       INDIA
2       AUS
3       NZ

//Players Table
PLAYER_ID PLAYER
1         Dhoni
2         Raina
3         Jadeja

//mapping table
Player_id Team_id
1           1
1           1
1           1
```

in this way if you want to give players extra statistics(columns) you can add to the Players table

while displaying you can join the tables and get the results

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain that by preceding it with

```
$cricket_names = str_replace(',', '<br />', strtoupper($cricket_names));
```

if that's what you mean, or just typing directly

```
str_replace(',', '<br />', strtoupper($cricket_names));
```

in place of `$cricket_names`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly place the below code in td .

```
preg_replace('/,/', '<br/>', $cricket_names);
```