# How to call all data with mysql from array that has been exploded

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf, explode

My values before explode 90PAS010,80PAS010

Then I split them using explode function

```
$site = $row["site"];
$exploded_site = explode(',', $site);
```

I want to print a table using fpdf by using every data obtained. This is my codes:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from site WHERE siteid='$exploded_site[0]'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       //do print table
    }
```

The problem is it only shows 1 data only because **$exploded_site[0]**.
How to change the **[0]** automatically when array have more than one value??

Thanks before

Comment: Try using ```where .. in```. ```in()``` operates both with single as well as multiple values.And then iterate over the result.

Comment: Use foreach to iterate over the array that you have got after explode. and run the query in that foreach loop. like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650938/php-explode-array-then-loop-through-values-and-output-to-variable

Comment: Sorry I can't understand it. Sorry I just started studying php...

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: sorry I'm really don't know about the risk. That codes for offline with localhost. But thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to perform a SQL query which fetches all site ids at once, and one of the many ways to do that would be using the `IN` condition.

```
$site = $row["site"];


/**
 * Function sanitizes and quotes each site id and returns a string to be used in the SQL IN operator.
 *
 *
 * @param string $site
 * @param mysql string
 * @return string
 */
function sanitizeSiteIds($site, mysqli $connect) {
    // split each site ids into arrays.
    $exploded_site = explode(',', $site);

    // escape all the site ids.
    $sanitizedSites = array_map(function($site) use($connect) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, trim($site));
    }, $exploded_site);

    // join all the site ids to something like:
    $sitesInStr = implode(',', $sanitizedSites);

    return $sitesInStr;
}


$site = sanitizeSiteIds($site, $connect);


// query will fetch all site Ids
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from site WHERE siteid IN ($site)");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    //do print table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a string `90PAS010,80PAS010`.

Don't split up and use it directly with MySQL's `in()` operator.

Use following code:

```
...

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from site WHERE siteid in($sites)");

...
```

UPDATE 1: It seems that siteid is a string column. So you may need explode the string, but actually for different reason.

Before using $sites variable given above, do the following,

```
$sites = array_map(function($v){
   return "'$v'";

}, explode(',', $sites));

$sites = implode(',',$sites)
```

UPDATE 2: I have used variable `$sites`. You may change it if it doesn't suit your context.

Comment: A proper example to show how to bind variables correctly would do OP wonders.

Comment: Sorry but my codes now doesn't display anything after change it to -> `WHERE siteid in($site)`

Comment: @FrankerZ https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php may be referred. I've started.

Comment: @RhonyRenyah I would request you to do - ```echo "select * from site WHERE siteid in($site)" ``` for once and run the resultant string in MySQL for once. (FrankerZ's comment to your question above for the injection problem is considerable).

Comment: @KalpashreeV.Bal here the result when do echo -> select * from site WHERE siteid in(20KED003,20PAS010)

Comment: @RhonyRenyah Yeah. I want you to run this query directly in MySql Db - on terminal / phpmyadmin or equivalent interface. This will either tell if there is any error in query making or something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FIND_IN_SET in MySQL.

You already have comma separated string, just make the change in the query like this:

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from site WHERE FIND_IN_SET(siteid,'$exploded_site')");

You can have a reference from here :

https://arjunphp.com/mysql-clause-comma-separated-valuesstring/